# I have an if function in a while loop, but it either ignores it or doesn't break

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, while-loop, pycharm, break

```
while True:
    print("We have entered in the open sea, but the current is pushing us. 
            We can veer left and"
              +"\nmiss the storm, or go straight through it. Type [left] or 
              [straight] exactly as it is in the box.")
    turnChoice = input()

    if turnChoice == "left":
        food = food - 2
        time.sleep(2)
        print("You missed the storm, but you lost a little food. Your 
            current 
          food level is 5. If you let it go to zero, "
          +"\nyour health will decrease.")
        break
    if turnChoice == "straight":
        time.sleep(2)
        random.randint(1,5)
        break
    if random == 1:
        food = food - 2
        print("You tried to go through the storm, but the ship was damaged. 
            You lost some food.")
        break
    if random == 2:
        print("The ship made it through the storm without taking damage 
                somehow. 
            You did not loose any supplies or health.")
        break
    if random == 3:
        print("The ship made it through. It made a lot of noise, but no 
            supplies were lost.")
        break
    if random == 4:
        health = health - 20
        print("The ship made it through, but there was damage. While you 
            were inside the ship, a stack of barrels fell on you."
            +"\n You took some damage, receiving a concussion and fracturing 
            your arm. But you will live.")
        break
    if random == 5:
        water = water - 2
        print("You made it through the storm, but some water barrels were 
            lost to the storm. ")
        time.sleep(2)
        print("Here is your water status, don't let it get to zero: ")
        print(water)
        break

    if turnChoice not in("left", "straight"):
        print("Invalid input, please try again.")
```

Sorry if it is formatted bad, I'm new to stackoverflow. I'm programming a word game for my English project. I'm trying to run these different 'if' functions inside the 'while' loop, but it either ignores them, or just loops the whole function. If you choose "straight", then it should pull a random number generator and choose a random scenario. If you choose "left", it just decreases your food. The "left" function works, but the "straight" does not. Also, I am trying to get it to break after it runs through either the 'left' function or 'straight' function, but I am not sure how to because of the 'if' functions. This is programmed on Pycharm, and I believe it is python 3.7.0.

Comment: In my case, it works fine for both **left** and **straight**. When you choose **straight**,  what does it select?

Comment: I'm going to try to help by asking a question. What does `break` do?

Answer (score 0):

Your `random.randint(1,5)` line isn't assigning to a variable, so none of the if statements are triggering.  Try doing something like

```
rnd = random.randint(1,5)

if rnd == 1:
    # stuff here
if rnd == 2:
    # stuff here
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. Break is used to exit you from the while loop. For python, the if statements will exit according to the indentation. So for straight to run and continue to your scenarios, you just remove the break after straight.
2. random.randint is getting you a random int between 1 and 5 inclusive but not saving it in the variable you are using to check scenarios. So you need to store it in random. The "random." part is just grabbing this function from the random module you imported.

This will exit the if statement and not the while loop when they type in **straight** and also assign random properly. These two changes fixed it for me.

```
if turnChoice == "straight":
    time.sleep(2)
    random = random.randint(1,5)
if random == 1: #rest of code
```